# Openshift 4.4 - Prometheus Unable to see metrics

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, prometheus, grafana

**oc version**:

Client Version: 4.4.3
Server Version: 4.4.3
Kubernetes Version: v1.17.1

**image**: quay.io/openshift-release-dev/ocp-v4.0-art-dev@sha256:6a5398997bd7ccddd8d0be0f0f2d9dcae8dddc01d54e6877437f07397c273048

There's not any error on other pods only get below exception at Prometheus Operator pod logs:

```
E0616 12:23:10.336040       1 reflector.go:280] github.com/coreos/prometheus-operator/pkg/prometheus/operator.go:477: Failed to watch *v1.PrometheusRule: expected resource version to have 40 parts to match the number of ListerWatchers
```

I checked the target that Prometheus is able to see, all node names reachable for Prometheus and it's able to obtain data. Everything looks fine but there's not any data at Prometheus and Grafana console. Any help would be appreciated.

[image: checked query for Prometheus]
[image: Grafana console]
[image: Prometheus console]

Comment: Grafana won't show anything until data is in Prometheus DB.

Comment: You might be hitting the following issue: https://github.com/coreos/prometheus-operator/issues/3218 But it says that the "watch" should be automatically restarted. Can you check if you can see any other errors?

Answer (score 0):

Solved. The problem was with lack of time sync on client side.